# How stop ajax Get url after success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have one modal to display a form, and 2 buttons: 'new' and 'edit'

'new' button:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#POPProduct">NEW</button>
```

'edit' button:

```
<a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary edit-product" href="http://domain.com/product/#POPProduct" data-id="10498f" data-toggle="modal">EDIT</a>
```

I use ajax to load data from db when i click edit

```
$(document).on("click", ".edit-product", function () {
    var uid = $(this).data('id');
    $('#POPProduct').off('shown.bs.modal').on('shown.bs.modal',function(e) {
        utilst.ViewPopEditProduct(uid);
    });
});

var utilst = {};
(function ($) {

    $.ajaxSetup({"error":function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
        alert(errorThrown);
        alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
    }});

    utilst.ViewPopEditProduct =  function ViewPopEditProduct(uid) {
        var data={uid:uid};
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            datatype:"json",
            url:"",
            data:data,
            cache:false,
            success: function(data) {
                data = JSON.parse( data );
                $('#product_name').val(data.name);

                $('#POPProduct').trigger("reset");
                $(".edit-product").unbind("click", ViewPopEditProduct);
            }
        });
    return false;
};

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

and this the modal

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="POPProduct" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        .....
    </div>
</div>
```

The modal works if I click the 'new' button after page load, but it stops working after I click the 'edit' button. Any idea how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Its stops because  of href="http://domain.com/product/#POPProduct"  its react on href value

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you remove event **shown.bs.modal** by using **.off()** so when you use **.on()** the **shown.bs.modal** is already remove.